# Woocommerce - change shipping cost via hooks (functions.php)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm using Woocommerce Subscriptions with Memberships and I would like to apply some discounts on the shipping cost according to the membership plan my user have. For example, silver members have a discount of -30% of all shipping method.
To check the current membership plan i use :

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();// Get current user ID

if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'silver' ) ) {
    //echo 'This is a special message only for Silver members!';
} else {
    //echo 'I\'m sorry, you are not a silver member. There\'s nothing here for you!';
}
```

But I don't find any way to change the shipping cost with functions..

Is it possible ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written some samples here: http://reigelgallarde.me/programming/woocommerce-shipping-fee-changes-condition-met/

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'woocommerce_package_rates' );
function woocommerce_package_rates( $rates ) {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ( ! wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $user_id, 'silver' ) ) { return $rates; }
    $discount_amount = 30; // 30%

    foreach($rates as $key => $rate ) {
        $rates[$key]->cost = $rates[$key]->cost - ( $rates[$key]->cost * ( $discount_amount/100 ) );
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Above code will do what you want for all shipping methods.

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confuse, your code doesn't work..I go into your article and try the basic code who set all shipping feed to 10, and it doesn't work too

Comment: Oh my bad, I have to empty my cart ! Thanks for the trick. But I have an another question, how to change the tax too ? Cause it's not correct now

Comment: @Efbi, I edited my answer... forgot to add `$user_id = get_current_user_id();`

Comment: Ok, i'll take another questio so
It's stunning that woo did not anticipate the tax issue.. Thanks a lot for this answer !